# Different library versions at runtime with plugins

Tags: java, dependencies, classloader, conflict

In a java application that uses plugins (such as Minecraft server, an IDE ...etc) many times it's necessary to use some library and shadow it in your .jar.

The problem comes across when **another** plugin also uses that library and also includes it in it's .jar but with a **different version**, both plugins will work fine until they meet together under the same classloader, then, the classloader will load just one version of the library and the other plugin will be running with a different version than the one it was designed for, leading to NoSuchMethodExceptions and/or different runtime behavior if the library is not backward compatible.

Note: This question is **not** about how to compile with maven when 2 dependencies have the same transitory dependency but in a different version. The problem is way different in this case because you cannot resolve or even detect dependency issues at compile time since the different versions of the library aren't going to be in the same .jar, neither in the same project, only under the same classloader at a given time by 2 plugins probably made by different authors with different purposes.

What is the general strategy to avoid such conflicts?

If I'm making my own library and it cannot be backward compatible, what can I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: Breaking backward compatibility is a sign of incompetence.  Java SE has *never* done it, in 22 years.  I understand you are at the mercy of some other libraries that have committed this sin, but why do you need to do it with your own library?  Why not deprecate obsolete methods, and have their implementations call the new, correct ones?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic java problem, and there are some major redesigns of java technologies underway to change this, though these are a while off (Java 9 or Java 10).

For now, the best thing you can do is explicit and regular dependency analysis of your projects.

To start, run this: `mvn dependency:tree`

You will be able to see multiple versions of the same dependency. Unfortunately when using external libraries, you may need to conform to the same dependency version as they use, or look for an updated build of the external dependency.

I have used a lot of time in dependency analysis, and it mostly has to be done manually (one of the bugbears of working with java...)

If you are making your own software, us **explicit API versioning** and make a significant change to the version whenever you make a breaking change.

For example, use "version 1.1", "version 1.2" and so on. Let people know that version `1.1.1` and `1.1.4` are backwards compatible with `1.1`, but as soon as you introduce an API breaking change (this happens), go to version `1.2` and force people to update.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is an issue faced in my application especially when you can't manage or maintain any third party pr external system. To minimize such situations you should create parent poms and put external dependencies there. Also regularly check if any mismatch or conflicts are there and if can be removed at development stage. Sometimes u reach dead lock when your application need a specific dependency but rest of the architecture is build on different one. Roll out new changes with custom build packs and huge changes and sometimes you can't help it. Precaution is better than cure in this case.

Answer (score 0):

@vikingsteve's answer explains how to design your APIs to avoid the problem.  Unfortunately, sometimes practical considerations will get in the way.  For example, when your code depends on two large libraries that (in turn) have dependencies on *different versions* of a third library.  And those versions are incompatible.

If you are in this situation, and you can't solve it by rewriting the libraries, bugging the library developers / vendors to fix it, etc., there are still a couple of options:

- You could restructure your software do that the libraries with conflicting dependencies are in separate applications; e.g. split them into a "client" and a "server", or "peers" communicating over a message bus, or a parent and child process talking over a pipe.
- You could restructure your codebase so that the two libraries are loaded in two separate child classloaders of your main classloader.  This would allow the two versions of the common dependency to be loaded by the two child classloaders .... and co-exist within the JVM.

Obviously, neither of these approaches is a magic bullet.  And both will entail some rework of your application.  But they *may* solve your "dependency hell" problems.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create another independent running jar application with the external dependencies I needed and perform the tasks there.